# Azure losing CREDITSSS

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I am using Microsoft student plan for azure for a project at my college. I have already deleted the resource group as well as some Network Reacher resource group. I am having a presentation after a few days and have only got 28 credits left. Why am I still getting charged?

I deleted all the resource groups. I was expecting credits to stop but its still going on.

Comment: Have you considered [viewing your usage and charges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/understand/download-azure-daily-usage)?